# Iterating through DataFrame using pandas for stocks

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

I am relatively new to python and `pandas`. 
I have a `DataFrame` with a few stocks and their associated 'low' prices for the past few days. I am trying to iterate through each stock (right now I only have 3 but will eventually have thousands) and then for each stock, I want to see if the current day's 'low' price is greater than yesterday's low price AND I want to see if yesterday's low price is less than the low price from 2 days ago. For each stock that meets this criteria, I eventually want to export them to a csv file.

```
list = ['IBM', 'AMZN', 'FB'] 

stockData = DataReader(list,  'yahoo', datetime(2016,06,8), datetime.today().utcnow())

low = stockData['Low']

low0 = low.iloc[-1]
low1 = low.iloc[-2]
low2 = low.iloc[-3]
```

The variables low0, low1, and low2 are probably not necessary but I do like how they splice out the specific data I want.

I then tried iterating over each stock in my list with my function:

```
for stock in list:
    if low0 > low1 and low1 < low2:
        print True
    else: 
        print False
```

This is the error I get:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

To identify whether the `Low` has been increasing for the last three days, you can use the following:

```
stockData = stockData.sort_index(ascending=False).iloc[:3] # reverse order, use last three days
```

either a condition that compares `Low` between adjacent days, and returns `True` if `Low` has been increasing in both cases:

```
stockData[(stockData.Low < stockData.Low.shift(1)) & (stockData.Low.shift(1) < stockData.Low.shift(2))]
```

Or check if the difference between the last three `Low` prices is negative (because the most recent day now comes first) for all days:

```
stockData.Low.diff().dropna() < 0).all()
```

So for your application:

```
for stock in ['IBM', 'AMZN', 'FB']:
    stockData = DataReader(stock, 'yahoo', datetime(2016, 6, 8), datetime.today().utcnow()).sort_index(ascending=False).iloc[:3]
    print('\n', stockData.Low)
    print(stock, (stockData.Low.diff().dropna()<0).all())
    print(stock, stockData[(stockData.Low < stockData.Low.shift(1)) & (stockData.Low.shift(1) < stockData.Low.shift(2))].Low.any())


 Date
2016-06-15    150.600006
2016-06-14    150.399994
2016-06-13    150.279999
Name: Low, dtype: float64
IBM True
IBM True

 Date
2016-06-15    713.349976
2016-06-14    712.270020
2016-06-13    711.159973
Name: Low, dtype: float64
AMZN True
AMZN True

 Date
2016-06-15    114.070000
2016-06-14    113.580002
2016-06-13    113.309998
Name: Low, dtype: float64
FB True
FB True
```

Comment: I get this Error when I do this: ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key

Comment: Not sure, are you using `stockData` directly from `DataReader`? Fixed the conditions, now  `2016-05-11` is the proper result with the previous two days having lower `Low` prices.

Comment: Okay. I see what you are doing and this is not what I am trying to do. I am trying to see if these criteria are met and get a True or False.  
    if low0 > low1 and low1 < low2:
        print True
    else: 
        print False

Comment: You mean `True` if there is a single case where the condition is met for the period? Just add `.any()` to the conditional statement, see update.

Comment: No actually it has to meet both conditions and not just one. Thanks.

Comment: It does meet both conditions because there is a `&` that forces both conditions to be `True` for the `boolean index` to yield `True` for the row in question. The entire statement prints `True` if there is a single case where both conditions are met.

Comment: Added more detail to clarify how this works. Please let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Also added how you can limit this to the last three days only.

Comment: Okay so this is what I am trying to do. I want to know if todays low (june 15) was greater than yesterdays low (june 14) and if yesterdays low was less than the days before's (june 13) low. I'm not interested in any data before that. If both of these conditions are met, i want that particular stock to be identified with True. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please see update. I printed out the last three days and how the condition correctly identifies things. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: For some reason, my results are for June 8, 9, 10 instead of the last 3 days. I see in your example, the dates are in descending order (15th, 14th, 13th) Mine are in ascending order so it says (8th, 9th, 10th) because of the iloc[0:3] in my case.

Comment: Use `.sort_index(ascending=False)` before `.iloc[]`.

Comment: I just used iloc[3:6] and it works for me now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a similar, but slightly different approach to this problem. I am using dummy values to demonstrate.

First, I create a dataframe.

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=3)
IBM = [5,3,2]
AMZN = [1,7,6]
FB = [4,7,9]
df = pd.DataFrame({'IBM': IBM,'AMZN': AMZN,'FB':FB}, index=dates)
df
          AMZN  FB  IBM
2013-01-01  1   4   5
2013-01-02  7   7   3
2013-01-03  6   9   2
```

I use `.shift()` to track how much the values went up or down during the second and third day compared to the first day and the second day in the dataframe. I do this by subtracting `df.shift(1)` from `df`. The first day value will be replaced by `NaN`.

```
df - df.shift(1)
           AMZN     FB     IBM
2013-01-01  NaN     NaN     NaN  
2013-01-02  6.0     3.0     -2.0
2013-01-03  -1.0    2.0     -1.0
```

If you prefer `True` or `False`, you can check if the values are higher or lower than `0`. So, in this case, `True` will mean up and `False` means down and the first day, the starting value, will be replaced by `False`.

```
df - df.shift(1) > 0
            AMZN    FB      IBM
2013-01-01  False   False   False
2013-01-02  True    True    False
2013-01-03  False   True    False
```